# What areas of research question the existence of the Planck length?

Tags: quantum-gravity, physical-constants

As a follow up to [What are the structures that exist at roughly the scale of the Planck length?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182690/), what areas of research question the idea of a [Planck length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) (or Planck scale)? Or if there are no areas of research, what specific qualities make it questionable?

Comment: The first question would be to prove experimentally that there is ANY physics at the Planck length. So far all attempts to do that have failed or even returned (statistically insufficient) indications that the Planck length does not exist as a physical scale, at all.

Comment: Interesting, would love to know more about the attempts. Do you suggest anything to read? Follow up question http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182739/

Comment: Have you done a literature search?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to question the existence of a mathematical definition.

Comment: The way this question is posed seems to be based on a premise that the idea of the Planck length is questionable. It is not. No areas of research question the idea. Not being in question usually indicates it is not considered questionable. Thus, not being questionable, there can not be any qualities that make it questionable. So we can't answer your last question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Planck Length is equal to $1.616199 \times 10^{-35}$m which is roughly $100$ billion billionth of the diameter of a proton. It is a base unit defined in terms of the five physical constants $G, \hbar, c, (4 \pi \varepsilon_{0})^{-1}$ and $\kappa_{B}$.

No areas of current research (that I know of) question the *idea* of the Planck length or indeed any of the underlying physical constants listed above;

Comment: Plenty of people in physics question the _physical_ existence of the Planck scale. Did you do any research on the subject?